# PHP - Can't print my sql result

Tags: php, sql, model-view-controller, yii, yii2

I'm using Yii2 framework.

I'm trying to get the number of records of my table and if the result is smaller than X number, show this number of records.

When I run my script, the error is:

> 'Object of class app\models\BusquedaCotizacion could not be converted
>   to string'

This is my code:

```
$query = BusquedaCotizacion::find()
                                ->select('cotizacion')
                                ->where('LIKE', cotizacion, 'BOB')
                                ->all();
            $bobresult = count($query);
            if ($bobresult < 6) {
                 echo ("No se obtuvieron todas las consultas de Bolivia. De las 6 posibles, se obtuvieron $bobresult.");
             }else{
                 echo ("Se obtuvieron todas las cotizaciones de Bolivia");
             }
```

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: This is because you are echo'ing the $bobresult variable inside the quoted string.

Comment: @Bizley  The use of a $var inside double quote is normal in PHP .. in this way the $vars is evaluated and the content i showed properly in the echo ... the error of th OP  came from others

Comment: @scaisEdge I know it's normal. Also I know that not every class has its __toString() implementation and this one doesn't. But you are right, the error probably comes from different place.

Comment: @Bizley in this case the user fails to calculate the result rather than a string, and obtains a collection of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $query result that you are trying to count with count($query)  is a collection of models  and not an array (or string) yuo are doing in the wrong wya

You should  use this way for count and models

```
$query = BusquedaCotizacion::find()
                            ->select('cotizacion')
                            ->where('LIKE', cotizacion, 'BOB');

$numRow = $query->count():

$models = query->all();
```

In $query you should prepare the Sql (PDO based) You need   and on this you can apply the function you need  ... count() for getting the count(*) and all() fpr getting al the models related;